# How to find the $n$-th derivative of the function $\log(1-x(1-x))$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

I know how to find the $n$ derivative of $\log (1-x)$ which is $-\frac{(n-1)!}{(1-x)^n}$, but how to find the $n$-th derivative of the function $\log(1-x(1-x))$?

Comment: Do you want the $n$th derivative or the $n$th derivative at a single point? If it's the $n$th derivative you are after then it would be better to use quadratic formula then split this into a sum of $\log$s

Comment: @Ninad Munshi $n$th derivative at the point $x=1/2$.

Comment: That's what my lawyer friend would call "burying the lede". Always include all of the context for whatever problem you're facing. Don't assume the path you chose was the best way to tackle the problem.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to write in terms of hypergeometric functions and attempt to use the rules in the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.5.i). In this care you have $\mathrm{log}(1-x(1-x))=-x (1-x){_2F_1}(1, 1;2: x (1-x))$

Answer (score 4):

By purely symmetry conditions we get that $x(1-x)$ is a parabola with a vertex at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ which means we can rewrite it as

$$x(1-x) = \frac{1}{4}-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$

Then the log becomes

$$\log\left(\frac{3}{4}+\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)$$

Finding the $n$th derivative of this function at $\frac{1}{2}$ is equivalent to finding the $n$th derivative of

$$\log\left(\frac{3}{4}+x^2\right) = \log\frac{3}{4} + \log\left(1+\frac{4}{3}x^2\right)$$

at $0$. The function on the right has a known Taylor series

$$\log(1+x)  = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^k}{k}$$

Can you take it from here?

The answer when you want to check is

> $$f^{(n)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \begin{cases} \log\frac{3}{4} & n=0 \\ 0 & n\text{ odd}\\ \frac{(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}+1}2^{n+1}(n-1)!}{\sqrt{3^n}} & n\text{ even}\\ \end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes, I think I can take it. Thnx.